# magic_quotes_gpc Does not show on php info page

Tags: php, magic-quotes-gpc

I am watching tutorial videos to learn php and I am trying to setup my computer for working on php. Although the videos tell me how to shut off the magic_quotes_gpc, it does not show at all on php info page so, could you please help me with that..

Note:

1) I am working on PHP Version 5.4.10

2) I am also using a regular text editor to make changes on php.ini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic quotes feature has been removed from PHP since version 5.4. You cannot enable or configure it anymore, it is permanently set to "off".